# Cosmos DB Stored Procedure Call returns "PartitionKey value must be supplied for this operation"

Tags: c#, stored-procedures, azure-cosmosdb, partitioning

I am developing a C# Azure Function and want to execute a stored procedure in Cosmos DB like the following:

```
string sprocName = "testSPROC";
int partitionId = contentJSON.partitionid;
RequestOptions requestOptions = new RequestOptions { PartitionKey = new PartitionKey(partitionId), EnableScriptLogging = true };
var sprocResponse = await client.ExecuteStoredProcedureAsync<Object>(
    UriFactory.CreateStoredProcedureUri(databaseName, collectionName, sprocName),
    contentJSON,
    requestOptions);
```

The CosmosDB collection is partition by partitionid. But when I want to execute the stored procedure, it returns:

> PartitionKey value must be supplied for this operation

Why?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

At the first glance everything looks fine but the order of the parameters passed to the SPROC and the request options is wrong. It has to be

```
var sprocResponse = await client.ExecuteStoredProcedureAsync<Object>(
                    UriFactory.CreateStoredProcedureUri(databaseName, collectionName, sprocName),
                    requestOptions,
                    contentJSON);
```

Then it works.